# Twitter Integration Callback Url

Tags: android

I am working on twitter login integration.While creating app on twitter it is asking for callback URL.I don't know from where to create the callback URL and how it works and what role it play.Please help

Answer (score 0):

You can use Firebase for create Redirect callback url.
Steps to create
Firebase-> Firebase Console-> Authentication -> Choose Twitter->

1. Enable Twitter
2. Enter API Key you get from Twitter
3. Enter API Secret Key also get from Twitter
   [image]
   Then you can get Re-Direct url

Comment: This solution worked for me.You are a genius.Thanks a lot .